# I want to design a scipt to send alert for Swap usage more than 85%

Tags: shell

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep Swap

SwapCached:            460248 kB
SwapTotal:             8388600 kB
SwapFree:              1031900 kB
```

I want to use this information to compare it with a threshold value. When the limit is reached, a warning shall be sent.
Could I get any help on this?

Comment: ![Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EMSxB.png) I have also seen scripts for alerts of memory utilization but this is not working with that method.

Answer (score 3):

In one line:

```
if [[ $(swapon -s | grep -v Size | awk '{print $4/$3*100}'| awk -F "." '{print $1}') -ge 85 ]]; then echo 'Swap alert'|wall -n;fi
```

You can test it changing `85` to other value to be sure that it works.

Comment: The `-s` option seems to be obsolete. You can use `swapon --bytes --noheadings | awk '{print $4/$3*100}'`.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you `total` and `free`, numbers:

```
cat /proc/meminfo |                  #read data
  grep -E "Swap((Total:)|(Free:))" | #just the two records that we need
  sed -re "s/[[:blank:]]+/ /g" |     #only one space field separator
  cut -d" " -f2                      #just the field that we need
```

You then need to do something with them. Maybe this:

```
(cat /proc/meminfo | 
   grep -E "Swap((Total:)|(Free:))" | 
   sed -re "s/[[:blank:]]+/ /g" | 
   cut -d" " -f2 && 
   echo "100 * r / 100 r - p" ) | 
     dc
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#!/bin/bash
threshold=$(( 8388600 * 15 / 100 ))
current=$(sed -n '/SwapFree/s/[^[:digit:]]*\([[:digit:]]*\).*/\1/p' /proc/meminfo)
[[ $current -lt $threshold ]] && echo "There is a problem" || echo "No problem"
```

Here we have calculated the threshold by taking `SwapFree` as a reference, if the percentage of swap free is less that 15% then an alert will be send.

In place of `echo "There is a problem"` do what you want to do like sending a mail or anything else.

You should run this as a `cron` job (may be after every 5 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

Strictly for "fetching the numbers", i would use:

```
$ grep Swap /proc/meminfo | tr -d "[a-zA-Z :]"
7228
3141628
3091688
```

Or, if you need the values in one line:

```
$ echo `grep Swap /proc/meminfo | tr -d "[a-zA-Z :]"`
7228 3141628 3091688
```

Comment: back-ticks are deprecated use `$()`

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like below:

```
#!/bin/bash

totalSwap=$(cat /proc/meminfo | sed -n 's/^SwapTotal: \+\([0-9]\+\) \+[a-zA-Z]\+$/\1/p')
freeSwap=$(cat /proc/meminfo | sed -n 's/^SwapFree: \+\([0-9]\+\) \+[a-zA-Z]\+$/\1/p')
usedSwap=$(( $totalSwap - $freeSwap ))
usedPctSwap=$(( 100 * $usedSwap / $totalSwap ))

swapThreshold=85

if [[ $usedPctSwap -gt $swapThreshold ]]
then
    echo "Swap utilisation is at $usedPctSwap %" | mail -s "SWAP Utilisation Alert" your.email@yourdomain
fi
```

Obviously, feel free to change this to meet your specific needs. e.g. you may have a method of alerting that's preferable over a simple email.

You could then schedule this by adding it to the crontab